# Firefox page-mod and iframe not loading

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

So, I'm developping a firefox plugin based on page mod and iframe. The chrome version using iframe within content script is working perfectly.

So basically, I inject a button, when the button is pressed he change the display type of a div containing some windowing stuff (to make a movable window within the browser and a close button) and this window contain an iframe. The iframe contain the application which is entirely contained within the plugin package, just make few ajax calls to a server to refresh the local storage datas.

I can inject the open button, the windowing stuffs and the iframe but whenever what I put in the iframe, the content is not loading. (excepted in one case, but not what I want).

To set the content of the iframe I basically :

- retrieve the url within the resources : require("sdk/self").url("index.html")
- Send it to my injector with a message
- Set it in the iframe with : iframe.setAttribute("src", iframeSource);

Here's what's injected in the page :

```
<div id="iframeContainer" style="border: medium none; width: 550px; height: 600px; background…olute; top: 50px; right: 10px; z-index: 200; display: block;">

<iframe id="master" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" src="resource://jid1-83zazep6ncytaa-at-jetpack/myaddon/data/index.html" style="border:none; width:550px; height:600px; background-color: transparent; position:absolute; z-index: 100; cursor:default;">

    #document
        <html>
            <head></head>
            <body></body>
        </html>

</iframe>
    <div id="clsBtn" style="border:none; width:25px; height:25px; position:absolute; top: 8px; right: 20px; z-index: 301;">
        <div id="closeShadow" style="width: 0px; height: 0px; box-shadow: 12px 12px 8px 8px rgb(255, 255, 128); z-index: 302; display: none;"></div>
        <img src="resource://jid1-83zazep6ncytaa-at-jetpack/myaddon/data/images/cross.png" style="border:none; width:25px; height:25px; position:absolute; z-index: 303; cursor:pointer;" title="Close"></img>
    </div>

</div>
<div id="openBtn" style="border:none; width:50px; height:50px; position:absolute; bottom: 5px; right: 10px; z-index: 301;">

    <div id="openShadow" style="width: 0px; height: 0px; box-shadow: 25px 25px 25px 15px rgb(255, 255, 255); z-index: 302; display: none;"></div>
    <img src="resource://jid1-83zazep6ncytaa-at-jetpack/myaddon/data/images/icon.png" style="border:none; width:50px; height:50px; position:absolute; z-index: 303; cursor:pointer;" title="Open TSO trade"></img>

</div>
<div id="headerDiv" style="border: medium none; width: 480px; height: 23px; position: a…peat scroll 0% 0% transparent; cursor: move; display: block;"></div>
```

If I browse resource://jid1-83zazep6ncytaa-at-jetpack/myaddon/data/index.html I get the page rendered correctly (css and js functionnal).
Also the two buttons and the header are displayed correctly (images, style and associated js). So it's really on the iframe that is not loading and rendering.

In the Console I don't get any js error or security error.

If I replace the iframe content with google (and inject it on google), the iframe don't render too.

So do you have any ideas ?

*PS : There's one method that is working but not as I want. The problem with the method I've found is that the javascript is not running and I still have some styling issue. So not the way to go I think.*

```
// Load the document
var source = data.load("index.html");

// Replace the relative path with the packed paths
source = source.replace("css/style.css", data.url("css/style.css"));
source = source.replace("css/ico.css", data.url("css/ico.css"));
source = source.replace("css/jquery-ui.css", data.url("css/jquery-ui.css"));
source = source.replace("js/external/jquery-1.9.1.js", data.url("js/external/jquery-1.9.1.js"));
source = source.replace("js/external/jquery-numeric.js", data.url("js/external/jquery-numeric.js"));
source = source.replace("js/external/jquery-ui.js", data.url("js/external/jquery-ui.js"));
source = source.replace("js/trade/data.js", data.url("js/trade/data.js"));
source = source.replace("js/trade/main.js", data.url("js/trade/main.js"));
console.log(source);

// Encode the content
let content = encodeURIComponent(source);
let binarySource = "data:text/html;charset=utf-8," + content;

// When in the injector, set the "binary source" as content
iframe.contentWindow.location.href=iframeSource;
```

Comment: `require("sdk/self").url("index.html")` should be `require("sdk/self").data.url("index.html")`. Is that a typo or is that what's causing the problem?